# How i can define 2 .tsx files where each file render a different text

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, apps-development

I want to build an SPFX web part which render 2 buttons and when the user clicks on the button 2 popup should be shown + have 2 fields to enter the 2 Popups text, something as follow:-

[image]

So i did the following:-

inside the `MyModalPopupWebPart.ts`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'MyModalPopupWebPartStrings';
import MyModalPopup from './components/MyModalPopup';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './components/IMyModalPopupProps';

export interface IMyModalPopupWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  WhoWeAre: string;
  OurValue:string;
}

export default class MyModalPopupWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyModalPopupWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> = React.createElement(
      MyModalPopup,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        WhoWeAre: this.properties.WhoWeAre,
        OurValue: this.properties.OurValue
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('WhoWeAre', {
                  label: "who We Are"
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('OurValue', {
                  label: "Our value"
                }), PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: "Description"
                }),
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

inside the `MyModalPopup.tsx`:-

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './IMyModalPopupProps';
interface IPopupState {
  callchildcomponent:boolean;
}
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import {MYModal} from './MYModal';
import {MYModal2} from './MYModal2';
export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IMyModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IMyModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      callchildcomponent:false
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
    handler() {
      this.setState({
        callchildcomponent: false
      })
    }
    private Buttonclick(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

     this.setState({ callchildcomponent:true });


    }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> {
    return (
      <div>


       <DefaultButton onClick={(e) =>this.Buttonclick(e) } text="Our Value" />
       { this.state.callchildcomponent && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler = {this.handler}/>}
      
       <DefaultButton onClick={(e) =>this.Buttonclick(e) } text="Who We Are" />
       { this.state.callchildcomponent && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler = {this.handler}/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

inside the `MYModal.tsx` :-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <p>{myprops.WhoWeAre} </p>
        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};

const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };

const theme = getTheme();
const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  header: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
    theme.fonts.xLarge,
    {
      flex: '1 1 auto',
      borderTop: '4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}',
      color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
      padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
    },
  ],
  body: {
    flex: '4 4 auto',
    padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    selectors: {
      p: { margin: '14px 0' },
      'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
      'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
    },
  },
});
const stackProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
  horizontal: true,
  tokens: { childrenGap: 40 },
  styles: { root: { marginBottom: 20 } },
};
const iconButtonStyles: Partial<IButtonStyles> = {
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4px',
    marginRight: '2px',
  },
  rootHovered: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralDark,
  },
};
```

inside the `MYModal2.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal2 = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <p>{myprops.OurValue} </p>
        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};

const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };

const theme = getTheme();
const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  header: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
    theme.fonts.xLarge,
    {
      flex: '1 1 auto',
      borderTop: '4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}',
      color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
      padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
    },
  ],
  body: {
    flex: '4 4 auto',
    padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    selectors: {
      p: { margin: '14px 0' },
      'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
      'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
    },
  },
});
const stackProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
  horizontal: true,
  tokens: { childrenGap: 40 },
  styles: { root: { marginBottom: 20 } },
};
const iconButtonStyles: Partial<IButtonStyles> = {
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4px',
    marginRight: '2px',
  },
  rootHovered: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralDark,
  },
};
```

but the issue that currently whenever i click on any button i will always get the value as 1 inside the Popups (but the Popup should show 1 or 2 based on the clicked button)... so what is the issue exactly?

second question, is there a way to allow my popup to show rich text instead of just a plain-text? either by entering pure HTML code inside the "Who We Are" & "Our Value" fields and allow the popup to render HTML? or have these fields as Rich Text editors ? is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, regarding your second question: you should ask that as a separate question, because it is a separate question.

Now, regarding your main question:

At a guess I'd say what's probably happening is that *both* modals are getting rendered, and the "Who We Are" one is always getting rendered on top, so you are always seeing the "1" from the `WhoWeAre` property.

The reason I think this is that you are controlling the conditional rendering of both of the modals using the same boolean state property.

It doesn't matter which button you click, both buttons just set `callchildcomponent` to `true`, so then on the next render:

```
// callchildcomponenet is true, so MyModal2 will render
{ this.state.callchildcomponent && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler = {this.handler}/>}

// callchildcomponent is true, so MyModal will _also_ render
{ this.state.callchildcomponent && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler = {this.handler}/>}
```

What you need to do is set something up so that you have a way to differentiate which modal should be showing.

That way I personally would do it would be to change your controlling state property from a `boolean` to a `string`, and in your button clicks pass another parameter in to the button click handling function to set the state with a specific string that you can use to tell which modal should be shown.  Then in your other "handler" function that you use to close the modals, just set the state to an empty string which won't match any of your conditionals, and neither modal will show.

So I would change your `MyModalPopup.tsx` to look something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './IMyModalPopupProps';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { MYModal } from './MYModal';
import { MYModal2 } from './MYModal2';

interface IPopupState {
  showModal: string;
}

export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IMyModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IMyModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: ''
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: ''
    })
  }
  private Buttonclick(e, whichModal) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: whichModal });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> {

    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'our-value')} text="Our Value" />
        { showModal === 'our-value' && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'who-we-are')} text="Who We Are" />
        { showModal === 'who-we-are' && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help.. your code worked for me .. will add a separate question for the Rich Text, if you have the time please check it.

Comment: here is the new question if you can have a look https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298735/can-i-show-a-rich-text-inside-popup-for-our-spfx-web-part-instead-of-plain-text